# I am facing an issue wgere empty string getting converted to null when passed in request body with RestController SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, spring-restcontroller

I am facing a strange issue, I have a controller and I have a method which handles put request. The code for controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @PutMapping(path = "/test/service")
    public Result test(
            @RequestBody TestObject testObj) {
        log.info("Received  request with data {}", testObj.toString());
        try {
            String data = "get from service";
            if (data != null) {
                Result result = new Result();
                result.setSuccess(true);

                result.setSuccessResult(response);
                return result;
            } 
        }

    }
```

Here is my testObject:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class TestObj { 
    
    @NotNull(message = "Should not be null")
    private Integer sequence;
    
    private String message;
    
    private String userId;
}
```

Now when I make the following request:

```
curl --location -g --request PUT '{{baseUrl}}/test/test/service' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: asdasdasdadadasdadadsadasa' \
--data-raw '{
    "sequence":1,
    "message":"  "
}'
```

I see that "message" field in TestObj is null in logs though I am passing an empty string. Here is a sample output:

```
TestController:xx - Received request with data TestObj [sequence=1, message=null, userId=null]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

**Update**

The solutions in the other link do not work for me.

**Update 2**

Interceptor code:

```
public class Interceptor implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,
                filterConfig.getServletContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        try {

            String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
            String url = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL().toString();
            String body = extractPostRequestBody(req);
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            TestObj testObj = objectMapper.readValue(body, TestObj.class);

            LOG.info("IP " + ipAddress + ", Time " + new Date().toString() + "  url " + url);
            LOG.info("Body: {}", body);
            LOG.info("Test Request: " + testObj);
}

String extractPostRequestBody(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if ("PUT".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            Scanner s = null;
            try {
                s = new Scanner(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return s != null && s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are using Jackson, can you show its configuration? My guess is that you have `ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT` deserialization feature enabled.

Comment: Try adding this to your class: `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`. If that works, and you generally want this behaviour, you can configure it globally.

Comment: @JoãoDias Jackson is just added on the classpath via dependency. I believe this feature is enabled by default. Any idea how can I disable it?

Comment: It is not enabled by default --> https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT

Comment: @JoãoDias Ok thanks, in that case, I am not enabling it anywhere.

Comment: Then it should work. What happens if you send `userId` in the request?

Comment: UserId as empty string or a proper value? If I send it as a proper value, it still gets populated but message is still null.

Comment: In fact, what happens if you send a proper value in `message`?

Comment: There is no issue in that case, it gets populated properly.

Comment: @JoãoDias And FYI, I have an interceptor before the Controller, I tried to log the request body there, the value is proper there before getting deserialised to custom object but when it reaches the controller, at that point it is null.

Comment: Can you add the interceptor code to the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241186/discussion-between-aman-kush-and-joao-dias).

Comment: The code looks weird. Is that all? I guess not because the first try has no catch. Please include the complete code.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a `chain.doFilter(request, response);` call in your `Interceptor`.